# Should I manually allocate string ending char '\0' in c?

Tags: c

I'm new to c, and confused by string ending char '\0', should I allocate it?

for example, I want to store a string with a max length of 6;

If I use array, should I use `char str[6]` or `char str[7]`?

```
  char as[3] = "abc";
  printf("%s\n", as);
  //seems no problem
```

If I use char pointer, should I use `char *str = malloc(6)` or `char *str = malloc(7)`?

Comment: Yes, please. Add 1.

Comment: You want to store a string with a max length of `6`. You should use `char str[7]`. If you use char pointer, You should  use `char *str = malloc(7);` Also `printf("%s\n", as);
  //this has problem`

Comment: Remember that just because something appears to work, that doesn't mean it's correct. In your example, `char as[3] = "abc"`, there may or may not happen to be a zero byte following `as` in memory. `printf` simply *assumes* that it has a pointer to a valid string. The behavior is undefined.

Comment: In C, a _string_ includes the _null character_.  `char as[3] = "abc";` --> `as` is not a _string_ as it lacks a _null character_

Comment: You could answer the question yourself by compiling & running: `char as[] = "abc"; printf("%zu", sizeof(as));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an array that is pre-initialized, you don't need to write a number in the brackets. You can just write

```
char str[] = "this is my string";
```

And the compiler will automatically calculate the number of bytes needed.

But for `malloc`, you must add 1. Ex:

```
char *strdup(const char *str)
{
    char *ret = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    strcpy(ret, str);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: If I want to write a number, should I use 6 or 7 ?

Comment: @Sato You should write 7 to allocate memory for a string of six characters, since you need an extra one for the terminating character `'\0'`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using string length + 1. In your case you must use 7 while declaring the char array.
The example you provided would have worked because of the undefined behaviour shown by printf().

Answer (score 0):

In addition to stackptr's answer:

If you are planning to overwrite your array:

```
char str[30] = "abc";
...
strcpy(str, "Hello world"); /* This will overwrite the content of "str" */
```

... the length of the array must be the maximum length of the string plus 1.

In the example above you may write strings of up to 29 characters length to the array.

Note that the following definition:

```
char str[] = "abc";
```

... implicitly creates an array of 4 characters length so you are limit to 3 characters.